# Considering the current situation is it cheaper to fly with Qatar Airways?

Tags: air-travel, qatar-airways

Would it be cheaper to fly with them since they have very few passengers now-days? Or it's the other way around and they increase their prices to make up for their loss due to the lack of passengers?

Comment: Airline pricing is complex with many variables and sometimes counter intuitive. That said normally I would think along the same lines as you did however factors like higher fuel usage may drive prices up. See `But now more Qatar Airways flights will incur Iran's relatively high fee, which may push the airline's ticket prices up, driving passengers away.` https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2017/06/07/three-maps-explain-how-geopolitics-has-qatar-airways-in-big-trouble/?utm_term=.ec660f6b46e3

Comment: Why not just price the itinerary you want and see how they compare to competitors?  That's all that really matters in the end.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question once you have priced it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Would it be cheaper to fly with them since they have very few passengers now-days?`

Not necessarily.

Airline pricing is complex with many variables and sometimes counter intuitive. Pricing is both a science and an art and too many factors going into a particular airlines pricing algorithm to know definitively.

Factors like higher fuel usage due to longer distances and having to fly over more expensive airspace may drive prices up. See the [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2017/06/07/three-maps-explain-how-geopolitics-has-qatar-airways-in-big-trouble/?utm_term=.dd7108fbad94) which says

> But now more Qatar Airways flights will incur Iran's relatively high
>   fee, which may push the airline's ticket prices up, driving passengers
>   away.